# Bash: Display Nano Seconds With Date

Tags: bash, date

With `date` it is possible to generate formatted time strings like

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N"
```

With `date` it is also possible to create unix timestamps in nano seconds. Using

```
NANO_TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s%N)
```

Is it possible to use `date` to read in a nano second timestamp to create a formatted date string?

How can I pass a nano second timestamp to `date`?

I tried:

```
date -d$NANO_TIMESTAMP +%H:%M:%S.%N     
date: invalid date ‘1550736813798767689’

date -d@$NANO_TIMESTAMP +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N"
date: time 1550736813798767689 is out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803202/1485527) but without math.

```
NANO_TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s%N)
secs=$(printf "%1d\n" ${NANO_TIMESTAMP: 0 : -9})
nanos=${NANO_TIMESTAMP: -9 : 9 }
printf '\r%s' $(TZ=UTC date -d@$secs.$nanos +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N")
```

With `printf "%1d"` I want to make sure, that there is at least one zero in the `secs` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by first by converting the nanosecond value in EPOCH to seconds value in EPOCH and then use that for conversion to human readable strings

```
nano=1550736813798767689
date -d@"$(( $nano / 1000000000 ))" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N"
```

For even more accurate representation back, take the modulo of the nano second value

```
withNano="$(( $nano % 1000000000 ))"
withoutNano="$(date -d@"$(( $nano / 1000000000 ))" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")"
echo "$withoutNano.$withNano"
```

So putting this together in a wrapper function

```
from_nano_to_readable() {
    (( $# )) || { printf '%s\n' 'provide atleast one argument' >&2 ; }
    input="$1"
    withNano="$(( $input % 1000000000 ))"
    withoutNano="$(date -d@"$(( $input / 1000000000 ))" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")"
    printf '%s\n' "$withoutNano.$withNano"        
}
```

and call it as

```
from_nano_to_readable 1550736813798767690
2019-02-21-03:13:33.798767690
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to do the math (division and modulo) yourself.

```
> set -x

> timestamp_ns=$(date +%s%N)
++ date +%s%N
+ timestamp_ns=1550740150623261543

> date -d@$(( timestamp_ns / (1000 * 1000 * 1000) )).$(( timestamp_ns % (1000 * 1000 * 1000) )) +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N
+ date -d@1550740150.623261543 +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N
2019-02-21-10:09:10.623261543
```